# Are there any real-world uses for converting numbers between different bases?

Tags: numbers

I know that we need to convert decimal, octal, and hexadecimal into binary, but I am confused about conversion of decimal to octal or octal to hexadecimal or decimal to hexadecimal.
Why and where we need these types of conversion?

Comment: Actually, after some head-scratching I couldn't come up with any case when I have to use such a conversion. But when I was young we had to! Those old machines were programmed in assembler which was taking ONLY octal as input, and any decimal (e.g. desired breast size) should have been converted to octal first!

Answer (score 6):

Different bases are good for different purposes.

- Decimal is obviously what most people know how to deal with, so is good for output of real quantities to end users.
- Hex is short and has an even ratio of exactly 2 characters per byte, so it's good for expressing large numbers like SHA1 hashes or private keys and the like in a type-able format, particularly since those numbers don't really represent a quantity, so users don't need to be able to understand them as numbers.
- Octal is mostly for legacy reasons -- UNIX file permission codes are traditionally expressed as octal numbers, for example, because three bits per digit corresponds nicely to the three bits per user-category of the UNIX permission encoding scheme.

One sometimes will want to use numbers in one base for a purpose where another base is desired.  Thus, the various conversion functions available.  In truth, however, my experience is that in practice you almost never convert from one base to another much, except to convert numbers from some non-binary base into binary (in the form of your language of choice's native integral type) and back out into whatever base you need to output.  Most of the time one goes from one non-binary base to another is when learning about bases and getting a feel for what numbers in different bases look like, or when debugging using hexadecimal output.  Even then, if a computer does it the main method is to convert to binary and then back out, because current computers are just inherently good at dealing with base-2 numbers and not-so-good at anything else.

One important place you see numbers actually stored and operated on in decimal is in some financial applications or others where it's important that "number-of-decimal-place" level precision be preserved.  Sometimes fixed-point arithmetic can work for currency, but not always, and if it doesn't using binary-floating-point is a bad idea.  Older systems actually had built in support for this in the form of binary-coded-decimal arithmetic.  In BCD, each 4 bits acts as a decimal digit, so you give up a chunk of every 4 bits of storage in exchange for maintaining your level of precision in the base-of-choice of the non-computing world.

Oddly enough, there is one common use case for other bases that's a bit hidden.  Modern languages with large number support (e.g. Python 2.x's `long` type or Java's `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` type) will usually store the numbers internally in an array with each element being a digit in some base.  Then they implement the math they support on strings of digits of that base.  Really efficient bigint implementations may actually use use a base approaching 2^(bits in machine native word size); a base 2^64 number is obviously impossible to usefully output in that form, but doing the calculations in chunks of that size ends up making the best use of space and the CPU.  (I don't know if that's the best base; it may be best to use a base of half that number of bits to simplify overflow handling from one digit to the next.  It's been awhile since I wrote my own bigint and I never implemented the faster/more-complicated versions of multiplication and division.)

Comment: you neatly explained why different bases are in use, but utterly failed to explain why would one want to convert from one to another! :D

Answer (score 4):

MIME uses hexadecimal system for Quoted Printable encoding (e.g. mail subject in Unicode) abd 64-based system for Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 3):

If your workplace is stuck in IPv4 CIDR - you'll be doing quite a lot of bin -> hex -> decimal conversions managing most of the networking equipment until you get them memorized (or just use some random, simple tool).

Even that usage is a bit few-and-far-between - most businesses just adopt the lazy "/24 everything" approach.

If you do a lot of graphics work - there's the chance you'll want to convert colors between systems and need to convert from hex -> dec... most tools have this built in to the color picker, though.

I suppose there's no practical reason to be able to do other than it's really simple and there's no point not learning how to do it. :)

... unless, for some reason, you're trying to do mantissa binary math in your head.

Comment: Good one! IPv4 indeed mixes decimal and bitmasks (leading to binary) in one notation. Actually, IPv6 does the same: ::1/127, right?

Comment: Indeed, but I don't know many people that do the IPv6 calculations manually. :)  They either have them memorized or use a tool.  I have seen (and I also) do IPv4 manually pretty often.

Answer (score 1):

All of these bases have their uses.  Hexadecimal in particular is useful as a shorthand for binary.  Every hexadecimal digit is equivalent to 4 bits, so you can write a full 32-bit value as a string of 8 hex digits.  Likewise, octal digits are equivalent to 3 bits, and are used frequently as a shorthand for things like Unix file permissions (777 = set read, write, execute bits for user/group/other).

No one base is special--they all have their (obscure) uses.  Decimal is special to us because it reflects human experience (10 fingers) but that's really the only reason.

Answer (score 1):

A real world use case: a program prints error code in decimal, to get info from a database or the internet you need the hexadecimal format, because the bits of the error 'number' convey extra info you need to look at it in binary.

Comment: Followed by filing a bug report asking for a better error printout including an error code that can be looked up :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm there are occasional uses for this.  One use case would be a little app that allows user who wants to convert decimal to octal ... like you can with lots of calculators.

But I'm not sure I understand the point of the question.  Standard libraries typically don't provide methods like `String toOctal(String decimal)`.  Instead, you would normally convert from a decimal String to a primitive integer and then from the primitive integer to (say) an octal String.

Comment: sure. the only reason to convert between bases is to make a calculator function that lets users convert between bases. ;)

Comment: I wouldn't say "only" ... but it is certainly the most obvious example.